# Find and Replace Text in a Large TextFile (Delphi XE5)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to find and replace text in a text file. I have been able to do this in the past with methods like:

```
procedure SmallFileFindAndReplace(FileName, Find, ReplaceWith: string);
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    begin
    LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Text := StringReplace(Text, Find, ReplaceWith, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    SaveToFile(FileName);
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

The above works fine when a file is relatively small, however; when the the file size is something like 170 Mb the above code will cause the following error:
EOutOfMemory with message 'Out of memory'[image]

I have tried the following with success, however it takes a long time to run:

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.button_MakeReplacementClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs : TFileStream;
  s  : AnsiString;
  //s  : string;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(edit_SQLFile.Text, fmOpenread or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    SetLength(S, fs.Size);
    fs.ReadBuffer(S[1], fs.Size);
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
  s := StringReplace(s, edit_Find.Text, edit_Replace.Text, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  fs := TFileStream.Create(edit_SQLFile.Text, fmCreate);
  try
    fs.WriteBuffer(S[1], Length(S));
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am new to "Streams" and working with buffers.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Thank You.

Comment: Open the file, read a certain amounts of lines and perform a search/replace, then write the result to another temporary file. Continue reading replacing and writing until the file ends. After that, delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two mistakes in first code example and three - in second example:

1. Do not load whole large file in memory, especially in 32bit application. If file size more than ~1 Gb, you always get "Out of memory"
2. `StringReplace` slows with large strings, because of repeated memory reallocation
3. In second code you don`t use text encoding in file, so (for Windows) your code "think" that file has UCS2 encoding (two bytes per character). But what you get, if file encoding is Ansi (one byte per character) or UTF8 (variable size of char)?

Thus, for correct find&replace you must use file encoding and read/write parts of file, as LU RD said:

```
interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TFileSearchReplace = class(TObject)
  private
    FSourceFile: TFileStream;
    FtmpFile: TFileStream;
    FEncoding: TEncoding;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Replace(const AFrom, ATo: string; ReplaceFlags: TReplaceFlags);
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.IOUtils,
  System.StrUtils;

function Max(const A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if A > B then
    Result := A
  else
    Result := B;
end;

{ TFileSearchReplace }

constructor TFileSearchReplace.Create(const AFileName: string);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FSourceFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
  FtmpFile := TFileStream.Create(ChangeFileExt(AFileName, '.tmp'), fmCreate);
end;

destructor TFileSearchReplace.Destroy;
var
  tmpFileName: string;
begin
  if Assigned(FtmpFile) then
    tmpFileName := FtmpFile.FileName;

  FreeAndNil(FtmpFile);
  FreeAndNil(FSourceFile);

  TFile.Delete(tmpFileName);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TFileSearchReplace.Replace(const AFrom, ATo: string;
  ReplaceFlags: TReplaceFlags);
  procedure CopyPreamble;
  var
    PreambleSize: Integer;
    PreambleBuf: TBytes;
  begin
    // Copy Encoding preamble
    SetLength(PreambleBuf, 100);
    FSourceFile.Read(PreambleBuf, Length(PreambleBuf));
    FSourceFile.Seek(0, soBeginning);

    PreambleSize := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(PreambleBuf, FEncoding);
    if PreambleSize <> 0 then
      FtmpFile.CopyFrom(FSourceFile, PreambleSize);
  end;

  function GetLastIndex(const Str, SubStr: string): Integer;
  var
    i: Integer;
    tmpSubStr, tmpStr: string;
  begin
    if not(rfIgnoreCase in ReplaceFlags) then
      begin
        i := Pos(SubStr, Str);
        Result := i;
        while i > 0 do
          begin
            i := PosEx(SubStr, Str, i + 1);
            if i > 0 then
              Result := i;
          end;
        if Result > 0 then
          Inc(Result, Length(SubStr) - 1);
      end
    else
      begin
        tmpStr := UpperCase(Str);
        tmpSubStr := UpperCase(SubStr);
        i := Pos(tmpSubStr, tmpStr);
        Result := i;
        while i > 0 do
          begin
            i := PosEx(tmpSubStr, tmpStr, i + 1);
            if i > 0 then
              Result := i;
          end;
        if Result > 0 then
          Inc(Result, Length(tmpSubStr) - 1);
      end;
  end;

var
  SourceSize: int64;

  procedure ParseBuffer(Buf: TBytes; var IsReplaced: Boolean);
  var
    i: Integer;
    ReadedBufLen: Integer;
    BufStr: string;
    DestBytes: TBytes;
    LastIndex: Integer;
  begin
    if IsReplaced and (not(rfReplaceAll in ReplaceFlags)) then
      begin
        FtmpFile.Write(Buf, Length(Buf));
        Exit;
      end;

    // 1. Get chars from buffer
    ReadedBufLen := 0;
    for i := Length(Buf) downto 0 do
      if FEncoding.GetCharCount(Buf, 0, i) <> 0 then
        begin
          ReadedBufLen := i;
          Break;
        end;
    if ReadedBufLen = 0 then
      raise EEncodingError.Create('Cant convert bytes to str');

    FSourceFile.Seek(ReadedBufLen - Length(Buf), soCurrent);

    BufStr := FEncoding.GetString(Buf, 0, ReadedBufLen);
    if rfIgnoreCase in ReplaceFlags then
      IsReplaced := ContainsText(BufStr, AFrom)
    else
      IsReplaced := ContainsStr(BufStr, AFrom);

    if IsReplaced then
      begin
        LastIndex := GetLastIndex(BufStr, AFrom);
        LastIndex := Max(LastIndex, Length(BufStr) - Length(AFrom) + 1);
      end
    else
      LastIndex := Length(BufStr);

    SetLength(BufStr, LastIndex);
    FSourceFile.Seek(FEncoding.GetByteCount(BufStr) - ReadedBufLen, soCurrent);

    BufStr := StringReplace(BufStr, AFrom, ATo, ReplaceFlags);
    DestBytes := FEncoding.GetBytes(BufStr);
    FtmpFile.Write(DestBytes, Length(DestBytes));
  end;

var
  Buf: TBytes;
  BufLen: Integer;
  bReplaced: Boolean;
begin
  FSourceFile.Seek(0, soBeginning);
  FtmpFile.Size := 0;
  CopyPreamble;

  SourceSize := FSourceFile.Size;
  BufLen := Max(FEncoding.GetByteCount(AFrom) * 5, 2048);
  BufLen := Max(FEncoding.GetByteCount(ATo) * 5, BufLen);
  SetLength(Buf, BufLen);

  bReplaced := False;
  while FSourceFile.Position < SourceSize do
    begin
      BufLen := FSourceFile.Read(Buf, Length(Buf));
      SetLength(Buf, BufLen);
      ParseBuffer(Buf, bReplaced);
    end;

  FSourceFile.Size := 0;
  FSourceFile.CopyFrom(FtmpFile, 0);
end;
```

how to use:

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Replacer: TFileSearchReplace;
  StartTime: TDateTime;
begin
  StartTime:=Now;
  Replacer:=TFileSearchReplace.Create('c:\Temp\123.txt');
  try
    Replacer.Replace('some текст', 'some', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  finally
    Replacer.Free;
  end;

  Caption:=FormatDateTime('nn:ss.zzz', Now - StartTime);
end;
```

Comment: Thank You. That worked perfectly. Also thanks for the code critique, very helpful. That is a very nice class, I will be able to learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 3):

Your first try creates several copies of the file in memory:

1. it loads the whole file into memory (TStringList)
2. it creates a copy of this memory when accessing the .Text property
3. it creates yet another copy of this memory when passing that string to StringReplace (The copy is the result which is built in StringReplace.)

You could try to solve the out of memory problem by getting rid of one or more of these copies:

e.g. read the file into a simple string variable rather than a TStringList
or keep the string list but run the StringReplace on each line separately and write the result to the file line by line.

That would increase the maximum file size your code can handle, but you will still run out of memory for huge files. If you want to handle files of any size, your second approach is the way to go.

Comment: Thank You. Pointing out the multiple copies was very useful, you provided a better practice for this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe refinement of Kami's code is needed to account for the string not being found, but the start of a new instance of the string might occur at the end of the buffer.  The else clause is different:

```
if IsReplaced then begin
    LastIndex := GetLastIndex(BufStr, AFrom);
    LastIndex := Max(LastIndex, Length(BufStr) - Length(AFrom) + 1);
end else
    LastIndex :=Length(BufStr) - Length(AFrom) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

No - I don't think there's a faster way that the 2nd option (if you want a completely generic search'n'replace function for any file of any size). It may be possible to make a faster version if you code it specifically according to your requirements, but as a general-purpose search'n'replace function, I don't believe you can go faster...

For instance, are you *sure* you need case-insensitive replacement? I would expect that this would be a large part of the time spent in the replace function. Try (just for kicks) to remove that requirement and see if it doesn't speed up the execution quite a bit on large files (this depends on how the internal coding of the StringReplace function is made - if it has a specific optimization for case-sensitive searches)

Comment: Thank You. I followed you suggestion and didn't find any major difference in time:
    Using: [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase] --> Time = 30.299 Seconds
    Using: [rfReplaceAll] --> Time = 31.040 Seconds.
So I'm going with the second option for now.

Comment: @MarkDavich: That surprises me a little bit. I would have expected it to be measureably faster when doing a case-sensitive search...

Answer (score 1):

Correct fix is this one:

```pascal
if IsReplaced then
begin
    LastIndex := GetLastIndex(BufStr, AFrom);
    LastIndex := Max(LastIndex, Length(BufStr) - Length(AFrom) + 1);
end
else
  if FSourceFile.Position < SourceSize then
    LastIndex := Length(BufStr) - Length(AFrom) + 1
  else
    LastIndex := Length(BufStr);
```