# Delete substring from text file

Tags: delphi

I need Delphi code to delete a substring from a text file. The problem is, a substring is not specific. We only know the first and the last character.

For example, we delete any character between '[' and ']':

Before:

> [P][strong]Stack Overflow[/strong] is very helpfull forum to get a knowledge.[/p]

After:

> Stack Overflow is very helpfull forum to get a knowledge.

I already read [Find and Replace Text in a Large TextFile (Delphi XE5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446733/), it is very helpful, but it uses a fixed substring, and I am still confused how to modify it like I want.

Comment: Search backwards (from the end of the text) for ']'. When found, make note and continue towards the beginning to search for '['. When found, delete the two markers and the text between. Repeat from index of the found '[' -1 until marker pairs not found anymore.

Comment: Do you have a programmer on your team?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "_confused_" with what exactly? Have you even attempted modifying the code to your needs? Can you please use formattings in your question?

Comment: I know how to do it on ordinary string. But it's not simple to do it for the text file. It will make your apps lag. Instead of judging me, if you smart enough can you provide the answer?

Comment: You did not indicate how big the file might be, so I assumed in my previous comment that you can read it into a string in one go before you remove the '[....]' parts of the content. Please edit to indicate largest file size you need to cope with. Also show what you have done yourself sofar.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do a text replace on a file is to read the file, do the replacement and write it out again. There's no built-in way that you can simply call

ReplaceInFile(<FileName>,<SearchFor>,<ReplaceWith>)

or any derivation thereof.

So, a crude way would be (assuming a modern delphi version) is:

```
TYPE
  TLineEvent = REFERENCE TO FUNCTION(CONST STR : STRING) : STRING;

PROCEDURE ProcessTextFile(CONST FileName : STRING ; Event : TLineEvent ; E : TEncoding = NIL);
  VAR
    SL : TStrings;
    I  : Integer;

  BEGIN
    SL:=TStringList.Create;
    TRY
      IF NOT Assigned(E) THEN E:=TEncoding.ANSI;
      SL.LoadFromFile(FileName,E);
      FOR I:=0 TO SL.Count-1 DO SL[I]:=Event(SL[I]);
      SL.SaveToFile(FileName,E)
    FINALLY
      SL.Free
    END
  END;
```

You then call it like this:

```
ProcessTextFile(FileName,FUNCTION(CONST STR : STRING) : STRING
                           BEGIN
                             <Put your code here>
                           END);
```

where `<Put your code here>` is the code to remove the [] areas.

This can of course be optimized in various ways, but I expect you get the gist of it...

Answer (score 1):

As a big fan of regex I suggest you to try this code:

```pascal
uses
    RegularExpressionsCore;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Regex: TPerlRegEx;
    sapp: string;
begin
    sapp := '[P][strong]Stack Overflow[/strong] is a very helpful website for knowledge.[/p]';
    Regex := TPerlRegEX.Create;

    try
        Regex.RegEx := '\[.*?\]';
        Regex.State := [preNotEmpty];
        Regex.Options := [preNoAutoCapture];
        Regex.Subject := sapp;

        if Regex.Match then
        repeat
            Regex.Replacement := '';
            Regex.Replace;
        until not Regex.MatchAgain;

        sapp := Regex.Subject;
    finally
        Regex.Free;
    end;

    ShowMessage(sapp);
end;
```

The trick is basically all made by this regular expression:

```pascal
        Regex.RegEx := '\[.*?\]';
```

It basically finds the first character that you need (in this case `[`), stops at the first instance of the closing bracket (in this case `]`) and takes those 2 plus all the characters inbetween (via `.*`). Don't forget to put the `?`, as otherwise the closing bracket will be the last instance in the string of the character that you need!

Made with Delphi 11. You can use the regex with every library that you have or prefer!